# Bootstrap form validation with Angular directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am able to get the form-control class from Bootstrap to behave well within a single HTML file. But when the form-control is defined from within a directive, the flags like $dirty are not being recognized. The class ng-dirty does appear.

HTML using directive:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" name="formExpense">
    <div frm-item ng-repeat="f in formdata2"></div>
</form>
```

Directive:

```
app.directive('frmItem', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: 'form.html'
    };
});
```

Template:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error':formExpense.{{f.name}}.$dirty}">
    <div class="col-md-6 text-right">
        <label for="{{f.name}}-entry">{{f.name}}</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input type="text" name="{{f.name}}" ng-model="f.amount" 
               class="form-control" placeholder="per month">
    </div>
</div>
```

$scope:

```
$scope.formdata2 = [{'name': 'housing'},{'name': 'medical'}];
```

Plunk: http://plnkr.co/JcanBWWTphGdL18v6NxZ

Comment: can you write plunker?

Comment: This is because interpolation based `ngModelController` creation does not work, so dynamically generated `name` property would not work. Options here are either to wrap each control in `ng-form` or search for directives that can generate model controller dynamically.

Comment: Added to Plunker: http://plnkr.co/JcanBWWTphGdL18v6NxZ